# How can I change the way a Head is printed on the notebook?

Tags: output-formatting, output, elided-forms

Consider the following simple example:

```
Interpolation[{0, 1, 2, 3}]
```

Despite the FullForm of the output of this expression is

```
InterpolatingFunction[List[List[1,4]],List[5,3,0,List[4],List[4],0,0,0,0,Automatic,List[],List[],False],List[List[1,2,3,4]],List[List[0],List[1],List[2],List[3]],List[Automatic]]
```

what I actually see in the notebook is:

[image]

How can I emulate this behaviour for a user-defined Head?